# Why is there extra "white space" between these floated Div's in FF and not IE?

Tags: html, css, firefox, internet-explorer, padding

Why is there so much extra space in FireFox between the two floated blocks?

```
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  #Container-900px { 
    width:900px;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
   }
    #Container-900px .left { float:left; width:435px; height:300px; }
   #Container-900px .right { float:right; width:435px; height:300px; }

  /* float clearing for IE6 */
  * html .clearfix{
    height: 1%;
    overflow: visible;
  }

  /* float clearing for IE7 */
  *+html .clearfix{
    min-height: 1%;
  }

  /* float clearing for everyone else */
  .clearfix:after{
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size: 0;
  }

   /* CSS3 Styles */
  #Container-900px { 
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #CCC; /* Firefox */
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 12px #CCC; /* Safari, Chrome */
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #CCC; /* CSS3 */ 
    }
   #Container-900px .left {
     background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
   }
   #Container-900px .right {
        background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
      }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Software</h1>
 <div id="Container-900px">
  <div class="left">

  </div>
  <div class="right">

  </div>
 <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the [doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) is omitted which causes IE to render in [quirksmode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug) (which is bad). If you have validated it with the [W3 HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/), it should also have errored about a missing doctype.

Adding a **strict** doctype should make the HTML and CSS to behave consistent among all major browsers (leaving aside the fact that MSIE has still [many bugs](http://haslayout.net/css/) left to potentially fix).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <!-- here you go -->
</html>
```

Further also give `#Container-900px .left` and `#Container-900px .right` a width of `445px` so that it fits nicely along the 10px margin of the container.

```
#Container-900px .left { float:left; width:445px; height:300px; }
#Container-900px .right { float:right; width:445px; height:300px; }
```

This way it looks good and the same in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to what? The size of the floated elements is 435px with 30px between them for the expected total of 900px. It looks the same in FF, Opera and Chrome. I don't have IE to look at. Perhaps you're missing a doctype?

Answer (score 0):

Use css reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
might help. it "normalizes" default rendering between browsers.